# Perform task for other host during role execution

Tags: ansible

I try to run a role (Ansistrano) on a host, which is fine:

```
---
- name: perform role
  hosts: host_one
  roles: 
    - ansistrano
```

I can specify other playbooks, which are included in the role:

```
ansistrano_specify_playbook: playbook.yml
```

But, now there is a single task I have to execute for another host, part of this playbook during role execution. I *cannot* achieve this with `import_playbook`.

```
- name: include task for other host
  import_playbook: other_host.yml
```

So, I'd like to perform a single task for another host during this role execution. Using `when` is not possible, since the role cannot be edited.

---

EDIT:

Note: The second host is not in the play/inventory during execution. So `delegate_to` will not work.

Comment: Would it be an option to add it to the inventory temporarily or permanently?

Comment: How can I add the host temporarily to the inventory during task execution?

Answer (score 0):

To delegate a single to another host, use the [`delegate_to` keyword](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation).

Example:

```
- name: include task for other host
  import_tasks: other_host_tasks.yml
  delegate_to: other_host
```

Here, `other_host` must be the `inventory_hostname` of that host in the inventory.

**Update:**
To add a host to the inventory during a play, use the [`add_host` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/add_host_module.html).

Alternatively, you could manipulate the inventory file itself, and then use the [`meta: refresh_inventory`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/meta_module.html) module.

Comment: The statement "`other_host must be ... included in any groups that the playbook is limited to`" is wrong. The example works fine with *other_host* not included in any group.

Comment: @VladimirBotka I edited my response, to avoid confusion anyways, but what about the case of limiting to a single host, or in the case that `other_host` was in a group. What I meant in my answer is that *if* you did put `other_host` in a group, then you'd need to include that in any limit, if one is given. I know I did have problems occasionally when using limiting while including other playbooks and using delegation.

Comment: As of "`I know I did have problems occasionally when using limiting while including other playbooks and using delegation`". Any link?

Comment: I've updated my original question. Sorry I wasn't clear enough.